# Counting and Outputting like characters between two strings

Tags: java, string

I would like to compare two user-defined strings and output the count of the number of characters shared between the two strings, without resorting to using arrays. I then need to output each of those characters. I understand the user-input part using a Scanner, but afterwards I am clueless.

For example, "hamper" as string1, and "happened" as string2 would return:

number of shared characters = 5

shared characters >> "h", "a", "p", "p", "e", "e"

Here is what i have so far.  It prints each character on a separate line though.  Is there a way without arrays to list them all on one line like above?:

```
    public class CountMatches {

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //Declare both Strings.
    String word1;
    String word2;
    int count = 0;


    //Call for User Input.
    Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input String 1 >> ");
    word1 = inputDevice.next();
    System.out.print("Input String 2 >> ");
    word2 = inputDevice.next();
    inputDevice.close();

    //Determine lengths and set label accordingly.
    String BigWord;
    String SmallWord;

    if (word1.length() > word2.length())
    {
        BigWord = word1;
        SmallWord = word2;
    }
    else
    {
        BigWord = word2;
        SmallWord = word1;
    }

    //Count and Display the like characters.
    for (int i = 0; i < SmallWord.length(); i++)
    {
        if (BigWord.contains(String.valueOf(SmallWord.charAt(i))))
        {
            System.out.println("both words contain the letter " + SmallWord.charAt(i));
            count++;
        }
    }

    //Display the count of like characters.     
    System.out.print("Number of like characters >> " + count);
  }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have `word1` and `word2`:

```
String biggerWord;
String smallerWord;
if (word1.length() > word2.length()) {
   biggerWord = word1;
   smallerWord = word2;
} else {
   biggerWord = word2;
   smallerWord = word1;
}        
for (int i = 0; i < smallerWord.length(); i++) {
  if (biggerWord.contains(String.valueOf(smallerWord.charAt(i)))) {
    counter++;
  }
}
```

This figures out which word is bigger. Then for the length of `smallerWord`, iterate over it one character at a time and see if `biggerWord` contains that character. If it does, increment the counter.
`counter` should then have the number of common characters by the end of the loop.

This was written freehand, so be aware of syntax and minor logic errors. Or I misunderstood your assignment. It should be pretty close though.

Comment: This is actually wrong, because you're assuming that word2 is the shorter one in your contains clause when you iterate over the smaller length. If you make word1="bbb" and word2="aaab", it will say they have no common letters.

Comment: You were correct it needed to be modified but for a slightly different reason. Calling it "wrong" was inaccurate (since it would've worked for many inputs) and a little harsh haha. Made an edit. Please verify it. Appreciate the feedback. With stuff like this I am likely to make dumb mistakes.

Comment: Yeah, wrong was a bad way to say it. Small logic mistake is better :). This works now.

Comment: thank you.  that definitely solved the counting problem.  Now all i gotta do is try to figure out the displaying the like letters it finds.

Comment: Just make sure you understand how this works so you don't get bitten on your exam. Display shouldn't be too tough, but feel free to ask another question if you get stuck after a good effort.

Comment: Also, if this solved your problem, can a brother get an upvote or an accept haha?

Answer (score 0):

A really nice way is to sort the string alphabetically.

```
sortedWord1 = new String(Arrays.sort(word1.toCharArray()));
sortedWord2 = new String(Arrays.sort(word2.toCharArray()));
```

What that does is turn the words into character arrays, sort them alphabetically, then makes them into a string again.

The next step is just to iterate from the beginning and print out all common characters. This would be easier since they're sorted.

```
int index1 = 0; 
int index2 = 0;
while((index1 < sortedWord1.length()) && (index2 < sortedWord2.length()) {
  if(sortedWord1.charAt(index1) == sortedWord2.charAt(index2)) {
    System.out.print(sortedWord1.charAt(index1) + " ");
    index1++; index2++;
  }
  else if(sortedWord1.charAt(index1)> sortedWord2.charAt(index2)) {
    index2++;
  }
  else {
    index1++;
  }
}
```

I haven't checked it for syntax errors, but it should be good.

Comment: sadly im not able to use Arrays for this.